# Is there a way for Firefox to preload a website?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Is it possible to have Firefox preload a tab for say Google Search but keep it hidden unless I try to go there?

My network is pretty slow and this would save me much time as I use Google often.

Comment: Not to be thick or anything, but a Google search would be much quicker to use from the built-in search bar since you don't have to load the Google front page at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll probably have to start doing that, I've had removed it in the past and forgot.  I'm still interested if there is an actual answer to the question.

Comment: @mtak: Words of wisdom,dude!

Comment: In case you start using the search bar, the key binding to set cursor focus on the search bar is CTRL+k .